# How do I automatically update the code in my HTML file when I upload an updated version of a file on github (eg my resume on e-potfolio)

Tags: html, github, web-deployment

I have made my e-portfolio and I am currently hosting it on GitHub. The problem I am facing is that I learn new skills almost every week which results me in updating my resume very often. So this means every time I update my resume, I need to upload in on GitHub and then I need to manually go into my HTML and change code in several places which feels very tedious. If anyone can give me a solution that can somewhat automate that process where if I upload my new resume, my HTML document automatically updates it self depending on the new name of my resume.

Answer (score 0):

- Store informations in a JSON File
- Configure you site to get data from that JSON file with JavaScript
- If all done properly you will be able to do what you wanted to achieve

For example

```
{
  "name": "Your Name",
  "education": [{
     "qualification": "Qualification Name",
     "starting_year": 2021,
     "ending_year": 2023
  },
  {
    "qualification": "Qualification Name",
    "starting_year": 2021,
    "ending_year": 2023
  }],
  "skills": ["Skill 1", "Skill 2"],
  "contact_info": {
     "facebook": "link",
     "github": "link"
  }
}
```